# No "Destroy" confirmation from Browser running Ruby/Rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, safari

Interesting problem...  I have created a small Ruby on Rails app that works just fine on localhost:3000 with SQLite but when I put it up on Heroku I loose the ability to destroy records with the scaffolded "Destroy" link for the table.

The behavior that is different is that when I am running on the localHost:3000 I get a browser dialog that looks like this:

[image]

When I run on heroku, I don't get the dialog and the "Destroy" doesn't nothing.  I am running under Safari and Firefox with the same behavior.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check if 'UJS' has been loaded correctly in production server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does precompiling the assets help?

In config/environments/production.rb set

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

locally run

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
git add .
git commit -am 'precompiled assets'
git push heroku master
```