# Rails app on Heroku won't destroy elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

I followed the rails getting started guide to create a simple [blog application](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). I deployed my app on Heroku and everything worked fine except for the destroy actions. I can't delete any of the articles or the comments associated with them. When I try to delete an article I get redirected to the article itself and when I try to delete a specific comment the "The page you were looking for doesn't exist.You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved." message shows up.

My app works perfectly locally (all actions work as expected) so I am a bit puzzled about this issue.
I already tried the suggestions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760017/no-destroy-confirmation-from-browser-running-ruby-rails-app-on-heroku) question but the problem persist.

The index view (which list the articles look like this)

```
<h1>Listing articles</h1>
 <%= link_to 'New article', new_article_path %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
                    method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

The comments view is the following:

```
<p>
  <strong>Commenter:</strong>
  <%= comment.commenter %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= comment.body %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.article, comment],
               method: :delete,
               data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>
```

Article controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", except: [:index, :show]

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end


  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end


  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

Comments controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", only: :destroy

  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end

end
```

This is the output of "heroku logs" right after I try to erase the article:

```
2014-07-01T16:49:05.502366+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-5f479ef43502f4271b7b26e7b1d2871e.js" host=eduardo-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=6289876a-1b06-46e7-9929-1a6731eb50d0 fwd="70.53.67.136" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12762ms status=304 bytes=232
2014-07-01T16:49:15.749410+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles" host=eduardo-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=4df2c6a4-6e1a-4602-a97b-e16038acd98a fwd="70.53.67.136" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=143ms status=304 bytes=727
2014-07-01T16:49:15.858590+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-778f77f22524bf46ac53b87d2f19943a.css" host=eduardo-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=75761c13-d9cc-41e0-aeb9-764f9619e897 fwd="70.53.67.136" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=10ms status=304 bytes=231
2014-07-01T16:49:15.875220+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-5f479ef43502f4271b7b26e7b1d2871e.js" host=eduardo-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=13f6c4c3-8cec-45ef-af36-d55186b35b71 fwd="70.53.67.136" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=14ms status=304 bytes=231
2014-07-01T16:49:19.133248+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles/2" host=eduardo-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=1ba4e1ca-70d3-42c3-bd03-105eaa6a4289 fwd="70.53.67.136" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=304ms status=304 bytes=727
2014-07-01T16:49:19.219454+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-778f77f22524bf46ac53b87d2f19943a.css" host=eduardo-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=314ae6a5-7cef-408d-8fe4-4e7c25abaf70 fwd="70.53.67.136" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=231
2014-07-01T16:49:19.242850+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-5f479ef43502f4271b7b26e7b1d2871e.js" host=eduardo-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=cdaffa86-b9a7-45ea-93ff-3c31a4e88f60 fwd="70.53.67.136" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=10ms status=304 bytes=231
eduardo@WebDisaster:~/Desktop/rails_projects/blog$
```

And the same right after trying to erase a comment:

```
2014-07-01T16:49:05.502366+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-5f479ef43502f4271b7b26e7b1d2871e.js" host=eduardo-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=6289876a-1b06-46e7-9929-1a6731eb50d0 fwd="70.53.67.136" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12762ms status=304 bytes=232
2014-07-01T16:49:15.749410+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles" host=eduardo-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=4df2c6a4-6e1a-4602-a97b-e16038acd98a fwd="70.53.67.136" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=143ms status=304 bytes=727
2014-07-01T16:49:15.858590+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-778f77f22524bf46ac53b87d2f19943a.css" host=eduardo-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=75761c13-d9cc-41e0-aeb9-764f9619e897 fwd="70.53.67.136" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=10ms status=304 bytes=231
2014-07-01T16:49:15.875220+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-5f479ef43502f4271b7b26e7b1d2871e.js" host=eduardo-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=13f6c4c3-8cec-45ef-af36-d55186b35b71 fwd="70.53.67.136" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=14ms status=304 bytes=231
2014-07-01T16:49:19.133248+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles/2" host=eduardo-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=1ba4e1ca-70d3-42c3-bd03-105eaa6a4289 fwd="70.53.67.136" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=304ms status=304 bytes=727
2014-07-01T16:49:19.219454+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-778f77f22524bf46ac53b87d2f19943a.css" host=eduardo-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=314ae6a5-7cef-408d-8fe4-4e7c25abaf70 fwd="70.53.67.136" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=231
2014-07-01T16:49:19.242850+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-5f479ef43502f4271b7b26e7b1d2871e.js" host=eduardo-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=cdaffa86-b9a7-45ea-93ff-3c31a4e88f60 fwd="70.53.67.136" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=10ms status=304 bytes=231
2014-07-01T16:54:09.802746+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/articles/2/comments" host=eduardo-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=be8d8432-1cee-48e6-ad43-cbd3c01a9b43 fwd="70.53.67.136" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=44ms status=302 bytes=919
2014-07-01T16:54:09.967749+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles/2" host=eduardo-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=0bc8a5c5-0c08-472a-bb68-5a083fcb6212 fwd="70.53.67.136" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=97ms status=200 bytes=2417
2014-07-01T16:54:10.113333+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-778f77f22524bf46ac53b87d2f19943a.css" host=eduardo-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=a121ff02-3ec1-4a10-91e5-e74f434adf49 fwd="70.53.67.136" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=43ms status=304 bytes=231
2014-07-01T16:54:10.121288+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-5f479ef43502f4271b7b26e7b1d2871e.js" host=eduardo-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=1244e984-9af1-4c0a-80ba-e3d8f00ffbb4 fwd="70.53.67.136" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=49ms status=304 bytes=231
2014-07-01T16:54:12.244713+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles/2/comments/4" host=eduardo-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=c0d28ac7-5bca-4703-bd8f-6b9483a969e6 fwd="70.53.67.136" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=29ms status=404 bytes=1829
```

besides the 404 status I do not really see (or understand for that matter) any indication  of an error.
Thanks again guys!

Comment: Can you post your code for both the view and controller please.

Comment: What does your log say?  I honestly can't see anything wrong with your code.